# MongoDB not-any operator

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is there something like a not-any operator for mongodb-queries?

I have the following setup:

```
const ConstructQuestion = new Schema({
  answerType: String,
  text: String,
});

const Construct = new Schema({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  questions: [ConstructQuestion],
});
```

I also have an array of ConstructQuestion-IDs. I now try to query all Constructs, that contain any questions whose `_id` is not in my ConstructQuestionID-Array.

In other words: I want all Constructs that have questions whose `_id` is **not any** of the IDs in my array

I can achieve the opposite of what i want using `$in`, which queries all Constructs, that have any questions whose `_id` is **any** of the IDs in my ID-array. sadly `$nin` wasn't the answer, as it doesn't match a Construct that contains all the questions in my ID-Array and more

---

**edit:**

To be very precise: I'm looking for a query that will give me all Constructs that contain at least one question whose id is **not** in my ID-Array

---

**result:**

With the help of [Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2614364/bertrand-martel)s answer my mongoose-solution now looks like this:

```
return this.construct.aggregate()
  .group({
    _id: '$_id',
    questions_id: {$push: '$questions._id'},
    construct: {$first: '$$ROOT'},
  })
  .unwind('$questions_id')
  .project({
    construct: true,
    questions_id: true,
    check: {
      $cmp: [{
        $size: {$setIntersection: ['$questions_id', usedQuestionIds]},
      }, {
        $size: '$questions_id',
      }],
    },
  })
  .match({check: {$lt: 0}})
  .exec()
  .then((results) => {
    const constructs = results.map((result) => {
      return result.construct;
    });
  })
```

---

**improvement:**

After adding the questionIds as array directly to the Construct on every create/update, i could remove the `group` and `unwind` stages, so my code now looks like this:

```
return this.construct.aggregate({
  $addFields: {
    check: {
      $cmp: [{
        $size: {$setIntersection: ['$questionIds', usedQuestionIds]},
      }, {
        $size: '$questionIds',
      }],
    },
  }})
  .match({check: {$lt: 0}})
  .exec()
  .then((constructs) => {

  });
```

Thanks again to [Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2614364/bertrand-martel) for this hint

---

**improvement 2**

Again, as a hint from [Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2614364/bertrand-martel), `$project` and `$match` can (in this case) be combined to `$redact`, with wich the code now looks like this:

```
return this.construct.aggregate({
  $redact: {
    $cond: {
      if: {
        $lt: [
          {$size: {$setIntersection: ['$questionIds', usedQuestionIds]}},
          {$size: '$questionIds'}
        ]
      },
      then: '$$KEEP',
      else: '$$PRUNE'
    }
  }})
  .exec()
  .then((constructs) => {

  });
```

---

**improvement 3**

I found out, that i could use [$setDifference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) and a single `$size` instead of `$setInsersection`and two `$size`. The code now looks like this:

```
return this.construct.aggregate({
  $redact: {
    $cond: {
      if: {
        $gt: [{$size: {$setDifference: ['$questionIds', usedQuestionIds]}}, 0]
      },
      then: "$$KEEP",
      else: "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }})
  .exec()
  .then((constructs) => {

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) + [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) :

```
var input = ["58c20f6d95b16e3046ddd7e9", "58c20f6d95b16e3046ddd7eb", "58c20f6d95b16e3046ddd7ec"];

Data.find({
    "questions._id": {
        "$not": {
            "$all": input
        }
    }
}, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

It will return all document that haven't got all questions specified in input `input` array. If the document is selected, it means at least one question in the `input` array is not in the document.

### Edit

As you want the intersection to be exact match for the `questions` document, you can use [`setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) available in aggregation to determine elements which are common to both array and take decision according to that :

```
var array = [
    new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId("58c20f6d95b16e3046ddd7e9"),
    new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId("58c20f6d95b16e3046ddd7ea"),
    new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId("58c20f6d95b16e3046ddd7eb"),
    new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId("58c20f6d95b16e3046ddd7ec")
];

Const.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "questions_id": {
            $push: "$questions._id"
        },
        "document": { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$questions_id"
}, {
    $project: {
        document: 1,
        questions_id: 1,
        check: {
            $cmp: [{
                $size: {
                    $setIntersection: ["$questions_id", array]
                }
            }, {
                $size: "$questions_id"
            }]
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        check: {
            "$lt": 0
        }
    }
}], function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

The first `$group` & `$unwind` take care of building an array of `questions._id`. The comparison is performed in the next `$project` with the intersection size and the size of `questions._id`.

### Edit 2

You can simplify `$project` + `$match` with a [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) that will keep dcouments matching the condition. With your newly added `questionIds` field, it's much simpler :

```
var array = [
    new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId("58c20f6d95b16e3046ddd7e9"),
    new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId("58c20f6d95b16e3046ddd7ea"),
    new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId("58c20f6d95b16e3046ddd7eb"),
    new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId("58c20f6d95b16e3046ddd7ec")
];

Const.aggregate([{
    $redact: {
        $cond: {
            if: {
                $lt: [{
                    $size: {
                        $setIntersection: ["$questionIds", array]
                    }
                }, {
                    $size: "$questionIds"
                }]
            },
            then: "$$KEEP",
            else: "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }
}], function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: I tried `not` + `all`, but when my Construct contains all questions specified in my array, and some more, `not` + `all` will not select that document (because `all` evaluates to true, and `not` will then make that false).

I'm looking for documents, that have at least one question that is not in my array, not the other way around.

Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: No it will evaluate to false because if there are some more that are not in the document, this will select the document as not all questions from the array are referenced in the document. Do you have an example where it doesnt work ?

Comment: Do you know of some mongodb-playground-website (something like plunkr for mongodb)? that would be helpful. anyway, in my currently not-working example, i have the following:

My constructs contains questions with the ids `1` and `2`. My array only contains `[1]`. in this scenario, my document doesn't get selected, because `all` says: yes, all input-array-elements exist, and `not` then says: because `all` says true, don't select this document. My ids are of course not only simple numbers, but you get what i'm trying to say

Comment: I'll have a look at it, when i'm home

Comment: I tried this now, and it does exactly what i need. I still have a little question: Are all these operations done on the DB, or is mongoose querying multiple times for this?

Comment: [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) is a mongoDB feature, those pipeline stage are performed by mongodb. For performance, it would be better to include a `$match` in the first stage because the `$group` is operation intensive as it will group all database documents

Comment: ok, i'll try to narrow the results down as much as possible in the first aggregatiopn-step. thanks for the hint!

Comment: Note that the first 2 stages `$group` & `$unwind` are just here to get an array of `questions._id`. If you could include a new field in your documents with this array (just pushing the question _id to this field each time you add a new question), you would only have a `$project` & `match` in the aggregation which would be more efficient

Comment: wouldn't i still need the `$unwind`? because my question-IDs would still be bound to their construct, but as id-array, not as complete questions

edit: ok, i see now what you mean, and i wouldn't need unwind ^^

Comment: The `$unwind` is  just to remove the array-in-array caused by grouping the subdocument. We want an array of questions._id like `questions_ids: [ ObjectId("58c20f6d95b16e3046ddd7e9"), ObjectId("58c20f6d95b16e3046ddd7ea") ] ` to be used with [`setIntersection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/)

Comment: After simply setting questionIds on every construct create and update, i successfully removed the group and unwind-stages :) Will add this info to my question

Comment: Please see my updated post to replace `$project` + `$match` with a `$redact`

Comment: Nice! works like a charm, i updated my question accordingly. Man, i'm really learning a lot about aggregations today :)

Comment: using `$setDifference` seems to be even nicer than `$setIntersection`. I again updated my question